# Where am I making a mistake in if else statement?

Tags: laravel, toastr

I can't return a toast error message. Where am I making a mistake? Message returns when successful.

My code is as follows:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50',
    ]);

    $data = array();
    $data['category_name'] = $request->category_name;

    $save = DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
    if ($save) {
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Saved :)', 'Success');

        return redirect()->route('admin.category');
    } else {
        Toastr::error('Error :)', 'Error');

        return redirect()->route('admin.category');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50',
    ]);

    $data = array();
    $data['category_name'] = $request->category_name;

    $save = DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
    if (!$save) {
        Toastr::error('Error :)', 'Error');
        
        return redirect()->route('admin.category');
    } else {
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Saved :)', 'Success');
        
        return redirect()->route('admin.category');
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro thanks but not working. Only work success method.

Comment: ok try  
        if ($validator->fails()) {  }
rather than if(!$save)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code.. You can use ->fails() function to check the inputs**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50',
        ]);
         if($validated->fails()){
          Toastr::error('Error :)','Error');
          return redirect()->route('admin.category');
         }
        $data=$request->only(['category_name']);
        $save = DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Saved :)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.category');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution . I created a validator myself

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50',

        ]);
        $notificationerror=array(
            'messege'=>'Category Added Error',
            'alert-type'=>'error',
            'positionClass' =>'toast-top-right'
        );
        if($validated->fails()){
            return redirect()->route('admin.category')->with($notificationerror);

        }

        $data=array();
        $data['category_name']=$request->category_name;
        DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
        $notification=array(
            'messege'=>'Category Added Successfully',
            'alert-type'=>'success',
        );
        return redirect()->route('admin.category')->with($notification);

    }
```